# How to get the upper-/lower machine-word of a double according to IEEE 754 (ansi-c)?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, ieee-754

i want to use the sqrt implementation of [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/).
This implementation defines (according to the endianess) some macros for accessing the **lower/upper 32-bit of a double**) in the following way (here: only the little-endian-version):

```
#define __HI(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __LO(x) *(int*)&x
#define __HIp(x) *(1+(int*)x)
#define __LOp(x) *(int*)x
```

The readme of flibm is saying the following (a little bit shortened)

```
Each double precision floating-point number must be in IEEE 754 
double format, and that each number can be retrieved as two 32-bit 
integers through the using of pointer bashing as in the example 
below:

Example: let y = 2.0
double fp number y:     2.0
IEEE double format: 0x4000000000000000

Referencing y as two integers:
*(int*)&y,*(1+(int*)&y) =   {0x40000000,0x0} (on sparc)
            {0x0,0x40000000} (on 386)

Note: Four macros are defined in fdlibm.h to handle this kind of
      retrieving:

__HI(x)     the high part of a double x 
        (sign,exponent,the first 21 significant bits)
__LO(x)     the least 32 significant bits of x
__HIp(x)    same as __HI except that the argument is a pointer
        to a double
__LOp(x)    same as __LO except that the argument is a pointer
        to a double

If the behavior of pointer bashing is undefined, one may hack on the 
macro in fdlibm.h.
```

*I want to use this implementation and these macros with the [cbmc](http://www.cprover.org/cbmc/) model checker, which should be conformable with ansi-c*.
I don't know exactly whats wrong, but the following example shows that these macros aren't working (little-endian was chosen, 32-bit machine-word was chosen):

```
temp=24376533834232348.000000l (0100001101010101101001101001010100000100000000101101110010000111)
high=0                         (00000000000000000000000000000000)
low=67296391                   (00000100000000101101110010000111)
```

Both seem to be wrong. High seems to be empty for every value of temp.

**Any new ideas for accessing the both 32-words with ansi-c?**

**UPDATE:** Thanks for all your answers and comments. All of your proposals worked for me. For the moment i decided to use "R.."s version and marked this as favorite answer because it seems to be the most robust in my tool regarding endianness.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `sizeof(int)` on your platform?  `LO` looks like it's getting you the right value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting pointers like you're doing violates the aliasing rules of the C language (pointers of different types may be assumed by the compiler not to point to the same data, except in certain very restricted cases). A better approach might be:

```
#define REP(x) ((union { double v; uint64_t r; }){ x }).r
#define HI(x) (uint32_t)(REP(x) >> 32)
#define LO(x) (uint32_t)(REP(x))
```

Note that this also fixed the endian dependency (assuming the floating point and integer endianness are the same) and the illegal `_`-prefix on the macro names.

An even better way might be not breaking it into high/low portions at all, and using the `uint64_t` representation `REP(x)` directly.

From a standards perspective, this use of unions is a little bit suspect, but better than the pointer casts. Using a cast to `unsigned char *` and accessing the data byte-by-byte would be better in some ways, but worse in that you have to worry about endian considerations, and probably a lot slower..

Comment: Okay, not that i would understand that construct at the moment, but it is working. But it is C99, isn't it. Maybe i should mention that i tried to  get a C90 version. I replaced these uint64_t and uint32_t types with unsigned long long int and unsigned int. That is surely not that portable, but working for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: One more thing: the code posted by me is the original one from fdlibm from the netlib software repository. Maybe you are right with the violation of aliasing rules. The question which arises is then: why don't they (the developers) care about that too? This library has been developed for many years, also a few years after the standard and it is used a lot (example: base for the java math functions). Maybe they had good reasons to do it like they did it. But i'm not able to differentiate and evaluate these implementation methods. For what it's worth :-).

Comment: Prior to C99, *all* casts to the wrong pointer types and union tricks were undefined behavior, which was so extreme that everyone just ignored the standard and pretended it was well-defined, and compilers didn't complain. Then compilers started to get smarter and realized that good optimization depends on ruling out the possibility of pointers aliasing one another, so C99 specified this all carefully, and compilers started to take advantage of the cases that were left undefined for optimization. Some people with old broken code are too lazy or stubborn to fix it...

Comment: If you need this to work with C90, you can use `uint32_t r[2];` in place of `uint64_t r;`, but then you need to deal with endian issues. Are there any real compilers (except for obscure embedded systems) without a 64-bit type these days? As for the C99 compound literals, those could be replaced with a temp variable union if necessary.

Comment: Thanks again. i just realised that i have a stdint.h header. So i can use your original version of code.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an union?

```
union {
    double value;
    struct {
        int upper;
        int lower;
    } words;
} converter;

converter.value = 1.2345;
printf("%d",converter.words.upper);
```

*(Note that the behaviour code is implementation-dependent and relies on internal representation and specific data sizes)*

On top of that, if you make that struct contain bitfields, you can access the individual floating-point parts (sign, exponent and mantissa) separately:

```
union {
    double value;
    struct {
        int upper;
        int lower;
    } words;
    struct {
        long long mantissa : 52; // not 2C!
        int exponent : 11;       // not 2C!
        int sign : 1;
    };        
} converter;
```

Comment: I tried your method and it is working. Because i'm not really a c-programmer, i have to learn more about these union-stuff (no expeience at all). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Union is nothing complicate - every part of it (in this case, there are 3 parts: 64-bit double and two 64-bit structures) is just mapped on the same place in the memory. No magic involved :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at the disassembly to see exactly why the existing "pointer-bashing" method does not work. In its absence, you might use something more traditional like a binary shift (if you're on a 64-bit system).

Comment: This would be surely the best approach. I will look into it. But because of the kind of black-box-natures of the tool, it may be possible not to get any view of the internal processing. Thanks for your answer.